# How is $\tan(4x)\sin(4x)\mathrm{d}x$ integrated?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm confused. I'm getting different answers for this integral. Various sites say that it's equal to $\ln|\sin(4t)-1|-1/4\ln|\sin(4t)+1|+1/2\sin(4t)$.

MyMathLab says that it's equal to $-1/2\ln|\sec(4t) + \tan(4t)|$.

How is this integrated? Please help.

Comment: First thing to do: differentiate the answers and see which one is correct.  Perhaps both are correct.

Answer (score 10):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
\tan(4x)\sin(4x) = \frac{\sin^{2}(4x)}{\cos(4x)} = \frac{1-\cos^{2}(4x)}{\cos(4x)} = \sec(4x) - \cos(4x)
\end{align*}